# Couldn't retrieve data from 1 datasource

Tags: 2011, ugc

Hi I have configured UGC and I am getting the above error and also unable to save from presentation side to DB.

```
[Info] Loaded Blueprint chain with 9 publications in 55 milliseconds
w3wp.exe Error: 0 : [UGC.PublicationExtender] Failed processing the request : System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.
 at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
 at Tridion.UGC.DataExtenders.PublicationExtender.ProcessRequest(XmlTextReader reader, PipelineContext context)
w3wp.exe Error: 0 : [UGC.PublicationExtender] Failed processing the request : System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.
 at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
 at Tridion.UGC.DataExtenders.PublicationExtender.ProcessRequest(XmlTextReader reader, PipelineContext context)
```

UPDATE 14/1:
I checked the connection between CM + odata2 (moderator side webservice) and it seems to work fine except for the occasional "Couldn't retrieve data from 1 datasource" on the CM explorer. I know it works because I can create and view comments on the component's Comments tab  in CMS explorer. However on the presentation side + odata1 (visior web service), I am not able to fetch the comments. It looks like the website is not making the webservice call to odata1. Also when I view the generated HTML format for the page, after this statement , I don't see the generated tag to fetch the contents . 
This is how the tcdl code looks like   which I have taken from the default UGC dreamweaver Template.
Am I missing something.

Comment: Is this log coming from cd_core.log? if not try to check it in order to know if there is a Database connection issue.

Comment: @EricHuiza: Please see updates to the Query above